# What does the phrase "entrenched software" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

I am not sure the meaning of the phrase "entrenched software" in the following sentence:

> The company was more concerned about persuading professional designers
>   who’d been using entrenched software to make a switch.

Here is some context. The company has transformed itself by developing new photo and designing apps. However, in the early phase it was not easy for the company to convince the users who were using "entrenched software".

There are two possibilities. The word "entrenched" may mean "established" or it may mean "installed" in the specific context of photo software

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entrenched can mean to be *dug in*. In the 1st and 2nd World War, troops that were *dug in* in trenches, were *entrenched*. These troops would be so used to being their trenches, they would hardly ever put their head above to see what was around (as it was dangerous).

When talking about software users though, it usually means people who are so used to using their particular software, they don't want to look at what other software is available, and it can be hard to shift their position. So it's not just that it was the  *established* software, it's that there's no willingness to use anything else, or even consider using anything else.

From [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=dictionary%20entrenched):
(of an attitude, habit, or belief) firmly established and difficult or unlikely to change; ingrained.